# Comma in the formula in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to compile a picture with the following formula in the label

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[label=left:$f_{23}(r(x_2,\tau)) $] (F012) at (0,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, every time I put a comma inside the formula, TeX writes me an error message:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\tau
l.207 \node[label=left:$f_{23}(r(x_2,\tau)) $]
```

I understand that this comma violates some internal rule of tikz, but how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing it with braces? `\node[label=left:{$f_{23}(r(x_2,\tau)) $}]`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Almost everywhere in tikz where commas are part of a value, you must enclose that value in braces. The following should work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[label=left:{$f_{23}(r(x_2,\tau)) $}] (F012) at (0,2) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can find it in the section »Setting Keys« of chapter V (Utilities) in the pgfmanual (emphasis added):

> `\pgfkeys{ key list }`
>   The key list should be a list of key–value pairs, separated by commas. A key–value pair can have the
>   following two forms: key = value or just key . Any spaces around the key or around the value
>   are removed. It is permissible to surround both the key or the value in curly braces, which are also
>   removed. *Especially putting the value in curly braces needs to be done quite often, namely whenever
>   the value contains an equal-sign or a comma.*